# Grouping 15 rating grades in 10 buckets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to group 15 corporate rating grades into 10 buckets. The grouping cannot be done in a random way - for example the rating grades 1 and 14 cannot be in a single bucket (constraint). The buckets should follow the order in which the rating grades are present,i.e., from rating grade 1 to rating grade 15 in ascending order. 
To explain the constraint better, few examples of combinations which are allowed are given below:

Example 1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,(10,11,12,13,14,15)

Example 2: (1,2),(3,4,5),6,7,8,9,(10,11,12),13,14,15
I have used () to represent one single bucket.

2 tools are available with me - Excel and R. Please guide me how I can code to create the combinations in R or excel. I have tried out 'combinat' package in R without success.

Any help is appreciated.

If you require any further clarification on the question, please do let me know. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define some objective to decide which grouping is better than the others.  For example, you might want the number of grades per bucket to be as uniform as possible.  Even this can be minimizing the maximum number of grades in any bucket, maximizing the minimum number of grades in any bucket, or minimizing the sum of squared errors from the average number of grades.  These may yield different results.  In general, [bin packing problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) are hard, but collapsing 15 to 10 should be "obvious".  Writing a program to do this would not be hard-after all there are only ${14 \choose 10}=1001$ groupings to check, so you can just try them all and compute your figure of merit.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this as more of a programming problem to list all possible groupings/buckets. The following code will do it. It is in C# unfortunately, but I hope the logic is clear enough for you to translate to R.

It produces $\binom{14}{5} = 2002$ lines of output - all possible groupings.

```
     GetStr(1, 15, 10, ""); // This is the initial function call.
```

```
 private void GetStr(int minNo, int maxNo, int numBuckets, string prefix)
        // minNo : the smallest number we are up to
        // maxNo : fixed as the initial maxNo
        // numbuckets : number of buckets left to use up
        // prefix : the string built up so far.
        // Create each next possible "bucket", append each to the existing "prefix"
        // then call itself recursively to process the remaining numbers.
 {
     if (numBuckets == 1)
         // Reached the last bucket: form it and print the full string
     {
         Console.WriteLine(prefix + "," + BucketStr(minNo, maxNo));
         return;
     }

     string x;

     if (prefix == "")
         x = prefix;
     else
         x = prefix + ",";
     for (int bucketSize = 1; bucketSize <= maxNo - minNo - numBuckets + 2; bucketSize++)
     {
         GetStr(minNo + bucketSize, maxNo, numBuckets - 1, x + BucketStr(minNo, minNo + bucketSize - 1));
     }
     return;
 }

 private string BucketStr(int minNo, int maxNo)
     // Return a single "bucket" string in the correct format.
     // E.g. BucketStr(3,4) gives "(3,4)" and BucketStr(4,4) gives "4".
 {
     string val = "";

     if (maxNo > minNo)
         val = "(";
     for (int i = minNo; i < maxNo; i++)
     {
         val = val + i.ToString() + ",";
     }
     val = val + maxNo.ToString();
     if (maxNo > minNo)
         val = val + ")";
     return val;
 }
```

First few lines:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,(10,11,12,13,14,15)
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,(9,10),(11,12,13,14,15)
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,(9,10,11),(12,13,14,15)
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,(9,10,11,12),(13,14,15)
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,(9,10,11,12,13),(14,15)
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,(9,10,11,12,13,14),15
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,(8,9),10,(11,12,13,14,15)
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,(8,9),(10,11),(12,13,14,15)
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,(8,9),(10,11,12),(13,14,15)
. . .
```